# Qual a diferença entre função e atribuição para array?

Tags: php, javascript, array, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação

Recentemente tenho realizado códigos em meus projetos aonde preciso adicionar itens em um array, logo não sei se devo usar funções nativas da linguagem para isso, como por exemplo:

```
array_push($meu_array, 50);
```

ou se simplesmente atribuo o valor, como por exemplo:

```
$meu_array[] = 50;
```

Queria saber qual a diferença entre eles? se existe algum que é mais performático ou mais aconselhável fazer, seria interessante também saber se existe algum parâmetro que devo levar em consideração quando uma situação semelhante acontecer

Comment: Já que marcou a tag javascript vale lembrar que para tal linguagem as coisas são um pouco diferentes, array_push é necessário para criar os índices automáticos e a atribuição direta sob array vazio gerará erro.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ambos não são equivalentes, `array_push` adiciona um item, e o `$meu_array[0] = 50;` editaria um item existente ou criaria um índice no zero.

O equivalente de `array_push` é o `[]` sem o índice, assim:

```
$meu_array[] = 50;
```

### No entanto array_push tem uma diferença

O que diferencia `array_push` do `[]` é que com ele você pode adicionar múltiplos itens, assim:

```
array_push($meu_array, 50, 60, 100, 9, 'a');
```

Quer seria equivalente ao:

```
$meu_array[] = 50;
$meu_array[] = 60;
$meu_array[] = 100;
$meu_array[] = 9;
$meu_array[] = 'a';
```

Então neste caso poderia ser mais interessante usar `array_push`

### Desempenho entre `[]` e `array_push`

Supostamente o uso de `[]` é um pouco melhor (é algo relativo), mas é provável que seja micro-otimização, ou seja a diferença é insignificante, ainda sim para escrever acho mais simples usar o `[]` do que `array_push` e além de simples você escreve menos:

```
$meu_array[] = 50;
array_push($meu_array, 50);
```

Para comparar a performance você pode usar a biblioteca [**phplegends/tests**](https://github.com/phplegends/tests), requer `composer`, o ideal para o teste é fazer ele em um array grande, então somente para teste `$minha_array = range(0, 10000);` isso deve bastar.

ficaria assim:

```
<?php
use PHPLegends\Tests\Bench;
use PHPLegends\Tests\BenchObject;

require 'vendor/autoload.php'; //Composer autoload

$minha_array1 = range(0, 10000);
$minha_array2 = range(0, 10000);

$bench = new Bench;
$bench->defaultCicles(9999); //9999 execuções

$test1 = $bench->addTest(function () use (&$minha_array1) {
    $minha_array1[] = 50;
});

$test2 = $bench->addTest(function () use (&$minha_array2) {
    array_push($minha_array2, 50);
});

$bench->run();

echo 'Test #1 (time): ', $test1->time(), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Test #2 (time): ', $test2->time(), PHP_EOL;
```

Resultado no PHP5.4:

> ```
> Test #1 (time): 0.041198015213013
> Test #2 (time): 0.051141023635864
> ```

Resultado no PHP7.2:

> ```
> Test #1 (time): 0.0042929649353027
> Test #2 (time): 0.0053369998931885
> ```

A diferença no PHP7.2 parece insignificante, em outra versões do PHP o resultado pode ser bem diferente, como no PHP5.4, ou até mesmo variar entre sistemas operacionais, como Windows e Linux

De qualquer forma isso é micro-otimização e **geralmente** não precisamos nos preocupar, exceto se realmente você for fazer milhares de execuções, mas para todos outros casos use o que lhe agradar mais.

Agora múltiplas adições:

```
...
$test1 = $bench->addTest(function () use (&$minha_array1) {
    $minha_array1[] = 50;
    $minha_array1[] = 60;
    $minha_array1[] = 100;
    $minha_array1[] = 9;
    $minha_array1[] = 'a';
});

$test2 = $bench->addTest(function () use (&$minha_array2) {
    array_push($minha_array2, 50, 60, 100, 9, 'a');
});
...
```

Resultado no PHP5.4:

> ```
> Test #1 (time): 0.053055047988892
> Test #2 (time): 0.056273937225342
> ```

Resultado no PHP7.2:

> ```
> Test #1 (time): 0.0079491138458252
> Test #2 (time): 0.0065710544586182
> ```

Note que múltiplas inserções foi um pouco melhor usar `array_push`, no entanto a diferença é minima, em todos testes, para 9999 repetições é que parece ser melhor, mas provavelmente o resultado varie muito, ou seja não existe motivos para se preocupar entre um e outro.

Answer (score 7):

Nestes exemplos não tem como comparar bem. Um adiciona um elemento ao *array*, ou outro atribui valor para o elemento 0 do *array*. Eles só fazem a mesma coisa se o *array* estiver vazio, então a semântica é diferente e só se obtém o mesmo resultado por coincidência.

Obviamente que o primeiro sempre criará um novo elemento no *array* aumentando seu tamanho. O segundo só criará o elemento se o índice 0 não existir.

O primeiro sempre adicionará um elemento com índice numérico incrementado com o maior número encontrado. O segundo pode usar a chave que quiser e nem precisa ser numérico.

Segundo uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559859/221800) o segundo é mais rápido. Não sei se ainda vale para as versões atuais. De qualquer forma me parece mais limpo fazer desta forma. E o que diz a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) faz todo sentido.

Há um teste na documentação que mostra uma [diferença brutal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#83388). Lembrando que isto pode não valer para as versões atuais. Mas há outro *post* mostrando uma [diferença bem menor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#84959). E ainda tem outro mostrando que se for fazer várias inserções o [`array_push()` pode ser mais rápido](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#116943).

Para obter a mesma semântica a atribuição teria que ser assim:

```
$meu_array[] = 50;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/Initialization.php).

Answer (score 5):

Os elementos adicionados com `array_push()` têm somente sus índices numericos apenas. Na forma de atribuição ele pode ser tanto numerico quanto associativo.

```
$arr = array('e1' => 1, 'e2' => 2);
array_push($arr, 3);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [e1] => 1
    [e2] => 2
    [0] => 3
)
```

Com atribuição:

```
$arr = array('e1' => 1, 'e2' => 2);
$arr['e3'] = 3;
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [e1] => 1
    [e2] => 2
    [e3] => 3
)
```