# União de array pelo índice PHP

Tags: php, array

Gostaria a saber se há a possibilidade, por exemplo, eu tenho 3 arrays onde estão estruturados da seguinte maneira.

```
$vet1 [
  0 => 'RECEITA',
  1 => 'PA - REVENDA' ,
  2 => 'IMOBILIZADO_' ,
];

$vet2 = [
 0 => 'teste 1',
 1 => 'teste 2' ,
 2 => 'teste 3' ,
];
```

Existe a possibilidade de eu realizar uma união de forma que fique no seguinte formato:

```
$vet3 = [
 0 => 'RECEITA, teste 1',
 ...
];
```

Comment: Eu trocaria o título de "União de array" para "Concatenação de valores de um array". União dá a se entender outra coisa.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o `array_map` para isso, passando os dois vetores nos argumentos e um callback:

```
array_map(fn ($m, $n) => $m . ", " . $n, $vet1, $vet2)
```

No código acima, `$m` pertence ao item iterado de `$vet1` e `$n` o item iterado de `$vet2`. Ao iterar outros vetores, adicione mais argumentos. Cada argumento pertence a um vetor.

Caso não queira usar [Arrow Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arrow.php), poderá usar o `function()` ao invés de `fn()`:

```php
$out = array_map(function ($vet1__item, $vet2__item) {
    return $vet1__item . ", " . $vet2__item;
}, $vet1, $vet2);
```

Que irá produzir o resultado:

```
array (
    0 => 'RECEITA, teste 1',
    1 => 'PA - REVENDA, teste 2',
    2 => 'IMOBILIZADO_, teste 3',
)
```

É funcional para arrays de diferentes tamanhos também. Nesse caso, é considerável tratar valores nulos quando os tamanhos forem diferentes.

[Documentação do `array_map`.](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays funcionam com índices, sabendo os índices basta usar:

- [`for(;;)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)
- [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Então pode gerar um novo *array*:

```
$vet1 [
  0 => 'RECEITA',
  1 => 'PA - REVENDA' ,
  2 => 'IMOBILIZADO_' ,
];

$vet2 = [
 0 => 'teste 1',
 1 => 'teste 2' ,
 2 => 'teste 3' ,
];

$novo = [];

foreach ($vet1 as $index => $value) {
   $novo[] = $vet1[$index] . ', ' . $vet2[$index];
}
```

com `for(;;)` seria:

```
...

$novo = [];

for ($index = 0; $index < count($vet1); ++$index) {
   $novo[] = $vet1[$index] . ', ' . $vet2[$index];
}
```

Note que os seus arrays seguem a mesma ordem de índice, para obter o índice de uma array pode usar `$variavel[índice]`, e para [adicionar itens a um array pode usar `$novo[] = ...`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/267158/3635). Então o importante é aprender o básico da linguagem e das arrays poderá fazer qualquer coisa conforme suas necessidades especificas, recomendo que comece pela documentação e manual:

- [Introdução ao PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php)
- [Introdução aos Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [Estruturas de Controle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)